# Create array in classic ASP, access array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp-classic

I have an ASP classic web page that loads the contents of files in a directory into a server-side array for later use.  I then parse this array in javascript to do the work I need.  However, my javascript cannot locate the array.  What do I need to do to access my array in javascript?

In ASP, I read the directory, and for each file in the directory, I add a `<select> <option>`, and an entry into my server-side array:

```
        Response.Write "<select name='cmbTemplate' id='cmbTemplate' onChange='templateIt();'>"
        Response.Write "<option value=''>[No Template]</option>"

        DIM fs,fo,fi,dot,ext,name,ix,ts
        CONST ForReading = 1

        Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        Redim vbTemplateArray(0)
        ix=-1
        If fs.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
            Set fo=fs.GetFolder(strDirectory)
            for each fi in fo.files
                ix=ix+1
                Response.Write("<option value='"&ix&"'>"&name&"</option>")
                Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile(strDirectory&fi.Name, ForReading)
                Redim Preserve vbTemplateArray(ix)
                While not ts.AtEndOfStream
                    vbTemplateArray(ix) = vbTemplateArray(ix) + ts.ReadLine
                Wend
                ts.Close
            next
        End If
        Response.Write "</select>"
    End If
```

I have seen it read that within my javascript block, I can use a javascript routine called VBArray to perform the conversion, but it doesn't seem to be locating the array I want to convert:

```
function templateIt() {
    var jsTemplateArray = VBArray(<%=vbTemplateArray%>).toArray();
    ...
}
```

I get the error: `VBArray: argument is not a VBArray object`

Suggestions?

Comment: Remember that the `<%=stuff%>` syntax is shorthand for `<%Response.Write stuff%>`. You can't `Response.Write` an entire array all at once; you have to iterate through its elements. (In fact, I'm surprised you're not getting a Type Mismatch error when the server tries to render the page.)

Comment: It's because vtTemplateArray can't be found, and the line renders as `var jsTemplateArray = VBArray().toArray();`  I would still like to know if there is a way around this, but I have re-written the code in question to create the array as a javascript array (rather than creating it as a vbScript array, then converting), effectively avoiding the issue.